# Distinct outside group in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called order_status_log, which logs who changed order statuses.

Simplified table and query below:

```
order_id     user_id    status    time
1            1          1         2016-01-27 19:35:44
2            2          2         2016-01-27 19:36:45
4            3          2         2016-01-27 19:37:43
2            1          5         2016-01-27 19:38:41
```

I also have SQL which counts changes by each user:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as count,
    user_id
FROM order_status_log
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count
```

Now I want to improve my query to count only first status changes in order.
In other words I need unique order_id with older time.
How I can change my query to do that?

Comment: you can do `order by time` for older time but what you mean by unique order_id. You are not selecting that field at all.

Comment: Do you want to find the count of unique orders that each user has ever updated?

Comment: I want to count only first status change in order, if someone set same status to order second time I don't wanna count that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM order_status_log o
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 'x'
    FROM order_status_log o2
    WHERE o2.user_id = o.user_id
    AND o2.time < o.time)
```